# MultiPage form using Worklight and HTTP adapter

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, ibm-mobilefirst

Trying to create a multi-page form in worklight that submits the data on page 1 and uses the jquery.validate plugin. The plug-in works as expected but when I try to load a new page using the Pages and Fragments demo from worklight, it fails and just loads the new page.

This is the button I use:

```
<input type="button" value="Go to Page2" id="LoadPage2Button" onclick="PAGE.loadPage();" />
```

and when I use JQuery.Validate plug-in and bind it to the form ID:

```
<form id="myform" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" method="get">
```

It only loads the next page and does not use the validate. But if I remove the onclick, then it validates the form, but does not switch the page. <--Obviously because it is not being processes by anything but even if I just put action="Page2.html" in the form tag, it won't load a new page in worklight. Or if it does load a new page, it is taken out of the worklight container and just loads a new web page.

Then I try and load a new page with the new page using:

```
PAGE.loadPage = function(pageIndex){
WL.Logger.debug("PAGE::loadPage::pageIndex: "+pageIndex);
        WL.Page.load("www/register.html", {

            onComplete: function(){ PAGE.init(); },
            onUnload: function() { PAGE.unload(); } 
        });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `WL.Fragment` and `WL.Page`, they are Deprecated.
See [Module 7.5 - Building a Multi-Page Application Exercise](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v505/Module_07_5_-_Building_a_Multi_Page_Application.pdf) and [code sample](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v505/module_07_5_MultiPageApplication.zip).
It gives an example using jQuery $().load() API to create a multi-page experience.